# WPF binding to obfuscated object can't find the property

Tags: wpf, binding, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to bind a ComboBox to the named cells of a SpreadsheetGear worksheet.

SpreadsheetGear is an obfuscated assembly, so that i my first guess.

```
<ComboBox Width="200" x:Name="comboBox" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Names, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

and the view-model propery is

```
private IWorksheet worksheet;
public IWorksheet Worksheet
{
    get { return worksheet; }
    private set { SetField(ref worksheet, value, () => Worksheet); OnPropertyChanged(() => Names); }
}
public IEnumerable<IName> Names
{
    get { return Worksheet.Names.Cast<IName>(); }
}
```

I am getting the following error in my Output window

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''ᜪ' (HashCode=1500138080)'. BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem='ᜪ' (HashCode=1500138080); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

I've tried returning `Worksheet.Names` directly, which doesn't inherit from Enumerable but DOES provide `GetEnumerator()`. That yielded the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Without more code, it's hard to say, but I'll take a random guess: Is `IName` an internal interface? Most code obfuscators will only mangle `internal`/`private`/`protected` classes/enums/interfaces...

Comment: The weird thing is, it's a public interface. Internal implementation, of course. http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IName.html

Comment: @NickStrupat Can you post any more of your view model class or XAML? Like what's your data context, etc.